# xul or sdk solution for adding items to [tools] menu in firefox

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Okay so i've created a menu item,

```
    var menuitem = require("menuitems").Menuitem({
    id: "menu_item_id",
    menuid: "menu_ToolsPopup",
    label: "menu_item",
    onCommand: function() {
    console.log("clicked menu item");
 },

});
```

Now i'd like to add an sub_menu_item to the above,

and this does'nt seem to work

```
var menuitem = require("menuitems").Menuitem({
id: "sub_menu_item_id",
menuid: "menu_item_id", <= parent element id
label: "sub_menu_item",
onCommand: function() {
console.log("clicked menu item");
},

});
```

Any ideas on how to add sub menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy paste this into your main.js this should add the context menu when you right click on the first tab element (in the tab bar) in all windows with tabs. just a test to show you how it works as you requested. this code is untested.

```
var {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require('chrome');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

    var myMenuJson =
['xul:menupopup', {id: 'myMenu1'},
['xul:menuitem', {label:'menu item1'}],
['xul:menu', {label:'menu item2 is submenu1'},
['xul:menupopup', {},
['xul:menuitem', {label:'submenu1 item1'}],
['xul:menuitem', {label:'submenu1 item2'}],
['xul:menuitem', {label:'submenu1 item3'}]
]
],
['xul:menuitem', {label:'menu item3 is before a seperator'}],
['xul:menuseparator', {}],
['xul:menuitem', {label:'menu item4 is after a seperator'}]
];



    let DOMWindows = Services.wm.getEnumerator(null);
while (DOMWindows.hasMoreElements()) {
let aDOMWindow = DOMWindows.getNext();
if (aDOMWindow.gBrowser && aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
var doc = aDOMWindow.document;
aDOMWindow.gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0].setAttribute('context', 'myMenu1');
var mainPopupSet = doc.getElementById('mainPopupSet');
mainPopupSet.appendChild(jsonToDOM(myMenuJson, doc, {}));
}
}







/*dom insertion library function from MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion*/
jsonToDOM.namespaces = {
html: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
xul: 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul'
};
jsonToDOM.defaultNamespace = jsonToDOM.namespaces.html;
function jsonToDOM(xml, doc, nodes) {
function namespace(name) {
var m = /^(?:(.*):)?(.*)$/.exec(name);
return [jsonToDOM.namespaces[m[1]], m[2]];
}

function tag(name, attr) {
if (Array.isArray(name)) {
var frag = doc.createDocumentFragment();
Array.forEach(arguments, function (arg) {
if (!Array.isArray(arg[0]))
frag.appendChild(tag.apply(null, arg));
else
arg.forEach(function (arg) {
frag.appendChild(tag.apply(null, arg));
});
});
return frag;
}

var args = Array.slice(arguments, 2);
var vals = namespace(name);
var elem = doc.createElementNS(vals[0] || jsonToDOM.defaultNamespace, vals[1]);

for (var key in attr) {
var val = attr[key];
if (nodes && key == 'key')
nodes[val] = elem;

vals = namespace(key);
if (typeof val == 'function')
elem.addEventListener(key.replace(/^on/, ''), val, false);
else
elem.setAttributeNS(vals[0] || '', vals[1], val);
}
args.forEach(function(e) {
try {
elem.appendChild(
Object.prototype.toString.call(e) == '[object Array]'
?
tag.apply(null, e)
:
e instanceof doc.defaultView.Node
?
e
:
doc.createTextNode(e)
);
} catch (ex) {
elem.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(ex));
}
});
return elem;
}
return tag.apply(null, xml);
}
/*end - dom insertion library function from MDN*/
```

Comment: Oops forgot, paste at top after the require('chrome') line : `Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');`

Comment: do you have the `var {Cc, Cu, Ci} = require('chrome');` before the Cu.import line?

Comment: i dont know how to compile or test sdk addons i do bootstrap stuff

Comment: move the jsonToDOM.namespaces and the library code to the way top of your moduel and try that

Comment: look at the gist i linked you man you gotta debug that error, its not on my side

Answer (score 0):

I helped someone with this the other day. But it relied on non-sdk solution. I also see you are not attaching the menu to a widget but just adding into a context menu. But just a fyi this is how I did it:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9523055

```
function doit() {
    //create and add the panel now
    var doc = document;
    var myWidget = doc.getElementById('widget:jid1-lwNbwJJiiMXM4A@jetpack-open-traveleye'); //we add the menu to this widget, we can add menu to anything by setting the context attribute of it to the id of the menu we want to give it

    var myMenuJson = 
                    ['xul:menupopup', {id: 'myMenu1'},
                        ['xul:menuitem', {label:'menu item1'}],
                        ['xul:menu', {label:'menu item2 is submenu1'},
                            ['xul:menupopup', {},
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label:'submenu1 item1'}],
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label:'submenu1 item2'}],
                                ['xul:menuitem', {label:'submenu1 item3'}]
                            ]
                        ],
                        ['xul:menuitem', {label:'menu item3 is before a seperator'}],
                        ['xul:menuseparator', {}],
                        ['xul:menuitem', {label:'menu item4 is after a seperator'}]
                    ];

    var mainPopupSet = doc.getElementById('mainPopupSet');
    mainPopupSet.appendChild(jsonToDOM(myMenuJson, doc, {}));

    myWidget.setAttribute('context', 'myMenu1');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, did'nt mention it before, but i'm trying to add a submenu for a menu item in firefox's MAIN menu(eg tools), not to the context menu,any idea how to append myMenuJson to the above menu?

Comment: basically, how does the (xul) or overlay file => fit into main.js

Comment: xul doesn't fit into main.js at all. you can however create xul on run time but thats no the sdk approach lets wait it out and see if someone has a sdk solution, if they dont ill give you a non-sdk solution. here's a heads up: [GIST - how to add menu item non sdk](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/8776519). This example is set up for a single menu item not a submenu, if no one replies here with sdk solution ill set that up for submenu.

Comment: yeah, could you let me know now..it's something really simple what i want, [Tools]->[menu_item]->[sub_menu_item1 & 2],

Comment: This is how I did it: [_ff-addon-snippet-CreateMenuWithSubmenuAndAttachToWidget.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9523055)

Comment: yeah @Notitidart, need the code snippet which appends myMenuJson to the firefox [Tools] menu, something simple i can test in Main.js?

Comment: copy paste that snippet i gave you 45min ago into main.js. set `var doc = document;` to mostRecentWindow and set `widget:jid1-lwNbwJJiiMXM4A@jetpack-open-traveleye` to any id in the document (like `addon-bar`) it will attach the context menu to it.